# Calling next results from WebService

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7

I develop WP7 app and I'm calling last 20 results from webservice and I wonder how to call next 20 when user goes to the end of listbox?

I have found some topics how to recognize when user reaches end of the list but I'm struggling how to re-call WebService and ask for next entries.

EDIT:

So okay, here is the thing. In my API I have two options:
- take some amount of results (like 10, 20, 30) and then show them all on the list
- second options is to ask API to give me like 3 pages of 20 records on each page

Thinking about second option: okay I can display just 1/3 pages and then when user goes down call another page (already stored on phone) but that makes no sense as user will download all records (even he don't want to see more than top 5...

The only idea is to call next results, but don't know how to re-call webservice on some point

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems more of a web-services related than a windows phone related. Because if you are getting some data from a web service then the web service provider should ideally provide you with some documentation on how to fetch next/previous records or entries.

Here are two links from Twitter API which gives you some idea on fetching the data in pages.

[Getting the home_timeline data](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/home_timeline)

[Working with Timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines)

Here is another link which gives idea on how to implement [paging in a Silverlight Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/270972/Paging-Data-from-the-Server-with-Silverlight) (I am not sure how far this method is compatible with WP app)

If this data couldn't answer your question, then update your question with some additional data like which url you are using to fetch the first 20 records etc